# (Dis)Prove that no vertex in a cycle graph has odd degree

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple graph G of N nodes and M edges, prove or disprove the following

> Given that G is a cycle graph, it has no vertex of odd degree

I really apologise for not showing any approach because I don't know how to proceed.
I have a half cooked approach that if we observe construction of a graph one node after another, then if we incorporate a vertex of odd degree in the graph,we will have an odd number of leaf vertices, and whatever way we connect them, we will never be able to get a cycle graph. But I am not sure if this is even correct, so please advise the correct formal approach to proving this. Also in the half cooked approach and by running through some examples, it seems that the claim above is true.

Comment: I thought every vertex in a cycle graph has degree $2$. I guess I don't understand what a cycle graph is. What is the definition of a cycle graph?

Comment: Oh yeah, nice catch. Thanks for that @bof, If you don't mind, can you direct me to a source that would give a formal proof?

Comment: @punter147 What is your definition of cycle graph if it does *not* make the degree-2 property an *immediate* consequence?

Comment: I don't think you need a formal proof, you just need the definition of a cycle graph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph

Comment: Thanks for the source @bof.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen the definition used in the question is the same as the standard definition. I get it now, I just need to follow the definition to prove this claim.

Comment: I apologise for the trivial query. I was looking into a graph theory problem that was asked in one of the google kickstart rounds. Thank you for tolerating my noobness :). I will try not asking such trivial questions again